# Qt and MacOs libiodbc.2.dylib and other libraries are missing

Tags: macos, qt, deployment

I'm trying to make a **macdeployqt** using MacOs 10.13.6 with Qt 5.12.2 clang 64bit. When I runtime command:

```
/Users/developer/Qt/5.12.2/clang_64/bin/macdeployqt /Volumes/Condiviso/MyApp/build-MyApp-Desktop_Qt_5_12_2_clang_64bit-Release/MyApp.app
```

I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: no file at "/usr/local/opt/libiodbc/lib/libiodbc.2.dylib"
ERROR: no file at "/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/lib/libpq.5.dylib"
```

I already had problems with libmysqlclient.20.dylib but downloading the mysql plugin I managed to resolve that error.
But for these two errors can somebody give me a suggestion or a link to find out how to resolve them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. For the **libiodbc.2.dylib** I had to install IODBC plugin that you can find on the IODBC site.
For the libpq.5.dylib I installed PostgreSQL 9.6.

After installing these two plugin I searched for the libraries in the Mac and then I create the path the application were searching for and I put the libraries in there.

So in my case installing the applications was not enough because the libraries were in different path.

Comment: how did you install them?

Comment: @AllanBowe with a homebrew installation try `brew install libpq; brew install libiodbc`;

Answer (score 0):

For `libpq.5.dylib`, you can download Postgres.app from here:

https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html